# JQuery Mobile Dialog Background

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

How can i set that color to black ? i tried with themeroller but i think you cant set it.

Thank you (Enjoy the pic )

[image: here's the problem]

---

EDIT WITH SOME CODE

`HTML` and `CSS` is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ilcavi87/kErwA/)

the jsfiddle doesnt work i used it only to store the code

Comment: Hey, can you post the code in jsfiddle.net, this looks like theme change

Comment: the css code made by themeroller ?

Comment: post your html and css files

Comment: i cant put the whole code, here's an example and the css above...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding this line in the style

```
.ui-overlay-a {
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

you have to control `.ui-overlay`, the a is the syle of jquery.

Thanks anyway